# Twig exception on PHP date_create()

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I want to calculate a voters age base on her birthday, in my entity, I created a function like this

//voters.php

```
public function getAge()
{
    $birthday = $this->birthday;
    $age = date_diff(date_create($birthday),date_create('today'))->y;
    return $age;
}
```

I render this in Twig like this

```
<td>{{ entity.getAge() }}</td>
```

But it shows the following error:

> "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Warning: date_create() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given") in DuBundle:Voters:index.html.twig at line 32."..

How to correct this problem? I use this in my older projects in Symfony 1.4 with Php templates and it render the current age of the voter without a problem.Why it doesn't work on Twig?

In older Symfony 1.4 I use this way

```
<td><?php echo date_diff(date_create($total->birthday), date_create('today'))->y; ?></td>
```

Comment: Return $age->y in your method and you should have an integer. The return of date_diff is a [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `$birthday` field is a `DateTime` object, you can use this approach:

```
public function getAge()
    {
        if (!$this->birthday) return "";// put here what you want if no birthdayprovided
        $now = new \DateTime('now');
        return $now->diff($this->birthday)->format("%y");
    }
```

Hope this help

Comment: I already tried this solution but i get this error "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Warning: DateTime::diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, null given"

Comment: Seems the $birthday is null, What can do in this case?

Comment: The date format in database is "1978-09-05".So after editing my orm and change birthday field into 'date' type,and using your example code provided,  I got this following code "Could not convert database value "1978-09-05" to Doctrine Type datetime. Expected format: Y-m-d H:i:s"

Comment: ok, so in the database is a string? We can convert it based on the format, the strange think is the error in your question based on an object...

Comment: @DanielleRoseMabunga check my update, check if the Y/m/d is the right date format or you are using a different. Hope this help

Comment: birthday field date type

Comment: So if it is a Date type, the correct mapping is a php datetime so was ok the first approach, without conversion.

Comment: maybe my its my twig template.I tried your first solution, and in my twig,  <td>{{ entity.getAge() }}</td>.Thiis is the error now An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Warning: DateTime::diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, null given

Comment: ok  @DanielleRoseMabunga give my last try, check my last updated cpde

Comment: case closed @Matteo.This is what I am looking for